# Property 'messaging' does not exist on type 'AngularFireMessaging' using firebase 7.14.6 and @angular/fire 6.0.0 FCM web push notification

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, angularfire2

In implementing FCM `Background Web Notification` getting below error in my service

`error TS2339: Property 'messaging' does not exist on type 'AngularFireMessaging'`

**messaging.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireMessaging } from '@angular/fire/messaging';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs'

@Injectable()
export class MessagingService {
    currentMessage = new BehaviorSubject(null);
    constructor(private angularFireMessaging: AngularFireMessaging) {
         this.angularFireMessaging.messaging.subscribe(
             (_messaging) => {
                 _messaging.onMessage = _messaging.onMessage.bind(_messaging);
                 _messaging.onTokenRefresh = _messaging.onTokenRefresh.bind(_messaging);
             }
         )
    }
}
```

**src/firebase-messaging-sw.js**

```
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.6/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.6/firebase-messaging.js');


firebase.initializeApp({
    apiKey: "xxxxxxxxxxx",
    authDomain: "xxxxxxxxxxx",
    databaseURL: "xxxxxxxxxxx",
    projectId: "xxxxxxxxxxx",
    storageBucket: "xxxxxxxxxxx",
    messagingSenderId: "xxxxxxxxxxx",
    appId: "xxxxxxxxxxx"
});

const messaging = firebase.messaging();
```

**installed packages**

```
"@angular/fire": "^6.0.0",
"firebase": "^7.14.6",
"@angular/cli": "^9.1.7",
```

i also tried to play with downgrading **@angular/fire** and **firebase** but no success.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`AngularFireMessaging` does not contain a property called `messaging`, you need to use the property `messages`:

```
         this.angularFireMessaging.messages.subscribe(
             (_messaging) => {
                 _messaging.onMessage = _messaging.onMessage.bind(_messaging);
                 _messaging.onTokenRefresh = _messaging.onTokenRefresh.bind(_messaging);
             }
         )
    }
```

https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/messaging/messaging.md#subscribing-to-foreground-messages

Comment: This gives another type error:
```Property 'onMessage' does not exist on type '{}'```
`@angular/fire@6.0.2` | `firebase@7.21.0`

Answer (score 9):

For error "Property 'onMessage' does not exist on type '{}'" I just added the object type to *_messaging* and now application runs:

```
this.angularFireMessaging.messages.subscribe(
    (_messaging: AngularFireMessaging) => {
    _messaging.onMessage = _messaging.onMessage.bind(_messaging);
    _messaging.onTokenRefresh = _messaging.onTokenRefresh.bind(_messaging);
  })
}
```

Using this dependencies:

```
"@angular/fire": "^6.0.3",
"firebase": "^7.21.0",
```

Answer (score 3):

This one worked for me:

```
this.angularFireMessaging.messages.subscribe(
    (_messaging: AngularFireMessaging) => {
    _messaging.onMessage = _messaging.onMessage.bind(_messaging);
    _messaging.onTokenRefresh = _messaging.onTokenRefresh.bind(_messaging);
  })
}
```

Answer (score 3):

try this it will work-

import { AngularFireMessaging } from '@angular/fire/compat/messaging';

Answer (score 0):

I change the version of @angular/fire and its work

```
npm i @angular/fire@5.1.1 --save
```

Answer (score 0):

I try this,

```
npm i @angular/fire@5.1.1 --save
```

and, maybe when running, just found error also
like"Property 'automaticDataCollectionEnabled' is missing in type 'FirebaseApp'"

and then i open file firebase.app.module.d.ts
just edit like this.

```
export declare class FirebaseApp implements app.App {

installations(): import("firebase").installations.Installations;
performance(): import("firebase").performance.Performance;
remoteConfig(): import("firebase").remoteConfig.RemoteConfig;
analytics(): import("firebase").analytics.Analytics;
name: string;
options: {};
auth: () => FirebaseAuth;
database: (databaseURL?: string) => FirebaseDatabase;
messaging: () => FirebaseMessaging;
storage: (storageBucket?: string) => FirebaseStorage;
delete: () => Promise<void>;
firestore: () => FirebaseFirestore;
functions: (region?: string) => FirebaseFunctions;
}
```